# url?id=1 How do i GET the id using a PHP MYSQL function?

Tags: function, get

I am learning how to use functions to organize my code better and cant seem to workout a mysql query that requires an external variable such as the ***url?id=1***. How is a ***mysql query function to get a variable from the url*** done?

How do i achieve this?

My function:

```
function item() { 

$itemid = $_GET['id'];

$t = "items";       
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $t WHERE id=$itemid") or die(mysql_error());  
$r = mysql_fetch_array( $sql );

$id         = $r['id'];
$date       = $r['date'];
$title      = $r['title'];
$location   = $r['location'];

}
```

Now when i call that function inside another file like this:

```
<?php ### // no entry

item(); // get item function

?>

<h1>Item View</h1>

<?php echo $id;?>
<?php echo $date;?>
<?php echo $title;?>
<?php echo $location;?>
```

I get no result from the above, i did test the function to make sure it was being called by printing some html and it does get called. It only works if i move the query inside the view file.

I have a strange feeling im missing something important that is to do with a php class as well, but i have been racking my brain online trying to understand examples.

If someone could please elaborate with a very simple example of how this is achieved i would be very grateful :-)

Update:

```
function external_db_connect() {

$database_hostname = 'localhost';
$database_username = 'user';
$database_password = 'pass';
$database_name     = 'table';
class DatabaseConnectClass {
public $database_hostname;
public $database_username;
public $database_password;
public $database_name;
public function databaseConnection($objDatabaseConnect) {
$this->_database_connection =
mysql_pconnect($this->database_hostname,
$this->database_username,
$this->database_password)
or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
return $this->_database_connection;
}
public function databaseConnectionSelect() {
$this->_database_connection_select =
mysql_select_db($this->database_name,
$this->_database_connection);
return $this->_database_connection_select;
}
public function databaseConnectionProcess($objDatabaseConnect) {
$objDatabaseConnect->databaseConnection($objDatabaseConnect);
$objDatabaseConnect->databaseConnectionSelect($objDatabaseConnect);
}
public function databaseConnectionMain($objDatabaseConnect) {
$objDatabaseConnect->databaseConnectionProcess($objDatabaseConnect);
}}

$objDatabaseConnect = new DatabaseConnectClass();           
$objDatabaseConnect->database_hostname = $database_hostname;
$objDatabaseConnect->database_username = $database_username;
$objDatabaseConnect->database_password = $database_password;
$objDatabaseConnect->database_name     = $database_name;
$objDatabaseConnect->databaseConnectionMain($objDatabaseConnect);   

}
```

Thanks in advance.
Jonny

Comment: How do you connect to your database?

Comment: well thats in a function and class, i used a simple script from a tutorial

Comment: have updated my post to show the database connect class, this i call first btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function item() { 


$username="root";
$password="";
$database="test";
$host="localhost";  
$itemid = $_GET['id'];

$t = "items";  
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");     
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=$itemid") or die(mysql_error());  


echo "<h1> Item view </h1>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
  echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
  echo "<p>" . $row['location'] . "</p>";
  }

mysql_close();
}


?>

<?php
    item();
?>
```

This should give you an idea on how to accomplish a select. however this is against SRP and DRY.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include first code into the second, or to send variables via form.

Comment: Going into a bit more detail in your answers is more helpful to the asker.